# After changing Atlassian password, I can log into Bitbucket with new password, but have to use old password with GIT

Tags: git, bitbucket

Changing password for the Bitbucket account, leads to changing password for the Atlassian account. I changed the password and now I can log into both Atlassian and Bitbucket with the new password. Unfortunatelly, I still have to provide old password for GIT in order to gain access to the server.

Any solution?

Comment: Do you have to enter the old password via HTTP protocol?

Comment: Are you using Windows operating system? Do you use a 3rd party application (example Source Tree?)

Comment: Old password is needed by pure git app, no external apps involved.

Comment: Did you find `~/.git-credentials` file?

Comment: In don't have saved passwords - every time I have to provide password manually, but it has to be the old passwords.

Comment: Have you tried `git remote show origin` and provided new password?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It turned out that it was problem in the backend of Bitbucket Cloud. After contacting with them via e-mail, in one day they "refreshed my Bitbucket Cloud account in their backend" and now GIT accespts only the new password.

Answer (score 0):

I think in order to solve the issue, you should re-add that remote once again.

First, you see all remotes.

```
>git remote  
bitbucket
github
```

Second, you remove repository where you changed password.

> git remote remove bitbucket

Note: This action will **not affect** your folder, your commit.

Third, you re-add that repo.

```
>git remote add bitbucket https://git.xxx.com/xxx.git
```

Finally, you use `git fetch --all` with your new password.